# Injective envelope in the category of left exact functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an Abelian category. $\mathcal{L}$ is the category of
absolutely pure objects of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{A})$ is the category of the exact left functors of $\mathcal{A}$ into $\mathcal{Ab}$ (category of abelian groups). The Theorem 7.31 of the Freyd's book *Abelian Categories and Introduction to the theory of functors* ([TAC Reprints version](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/3/tr3abs.html)) says:

- $\mathcal{L}$ is abelian and every object has an injective envelope

Freyd says (on page 149, before theorem 7.32) that by this proposition it can be concluded that he $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{A})$ has a injective envelope. But I do not understand why this can be concluded from this statement.

Comment: There was at some point a running joke about the number of mistakes in that book. I can't however find mention of an error relating to the bit your question is on.

Comment: This note (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08591.pdf) claims that putting together 7.10 and 7.13 you can conclude your statement. It looks quite sound to me.

Comment: Crossposted to math.SE, where I've answered it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327472/injective-envelope-in-the-category-of-left-exact-functors/3327724#3327724